# Regarding fork system call in linux

Tags: c++, printf, fork, stdout, stdio

Okay I am working with the following C/C++ code in linux:

```
int main() {
    printf("hello");
    Pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0)
            printf("I’m the parent!");
    else
            printf("I’m the child");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:
[image: program output screenshot]

My notes from my CS prof say the following:

> After a new child process is created, both processes will execute the
>   next instruction following the `fork()` system call. Please note that
>   Unix will make an exact copy of the parent's address space and give it
>   to the child. Therefore, the parent and child processes have separate
>   address spaces.

For this reason, I am extremely confused as to why it would not only output the current directory again but also the "hello" again? the only possible reason I could think that it would do this is the line that says it "copies the address space" is simply re-running all the commands before the fork but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your CS prof provides good notes. Given rsp's answer, think about what is happening if `"hello"` is still buffered in the output stream at the time of the call to `fork`. (p.s. if you are compiling C, just use `gcc` instead of `g++`, and always include `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string to enable *compiler warnings* -- they really help you learn to code properly, and `gcc` and `g++` provide darn good warnings) You can also provide `-o yourexename` if you don't like `a.out`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is technically just C yes but the class is taught in C++. And thanks for the tips! It has been a few semesters since I picked up some good old C or C++ and it's interesting, to say the least relearning all the intricacies again after doing languages like Java, Python, PHP, and JS which lack that low-level interaction with the system. Taking assembly next semester, wish me luck ;)

Comment: Good luck. Diving back into C and assembler will do one thing -- it will make you a better programmer regardless of the language you end up writing in. It is precisely the *"low-level interaction"*, that pays dividends. While high level languages hide the details of accounting byte-by-byte for memory use and addressing, understanding the nuts and bolts really helps you understand what all those high level abstractions are doing under the hood (with all their added zillion lines of code). It's humbling to climb down into the swamp, but the waters drain away soon enough.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin C++ is as low level as C in pretty much every aspect; might be even clearer (better object model, no "effective type" nonsense)

Comment: Try `strace` or a step by step debug!

Comment: @curiousguy It can be used in as low-level a manner as C can, but when you begin using the abstractions such as iostream, etc., it rapidly loses the low-level efficiency of C.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin iostream can be as efficient as stdio. The abstraction level of iostream is pretty much the same as stdio.

Comment: I don't disagree theoretically, but for real world I/O and memory use, it is quite a bit less efficient on memory use, etc. for comparable operations. Rather than a "he said", "she said", here are the numbers for reading `25481` lines of data into memory. C++ `read/stored 25481 lines in 0.00813842 sec. total heap usage: 76,465 allocs, 76,464 frees, 2,151,883 bytes allocated` (using `list<string>`, best of 10 runs). C `read/stored 25481 lines in 0.003850 sec. total heap usage: 25,494 allocs, 25,494 frees, 733,979 bytes allocated`. C++ is twice as slow and uses 3X the memory. (code on request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `printf`, the output is buffered. So, do a `fflush` or `\n` right after `printf`.

Adding the `fflush` or `\n` though forces the buffer to be flushed and outputted to the screen. This happens before the fork and hence is only printed once.

**C99 7.19.2p2**

> Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is
>   implementation-defined.
>
> **It doesn't define what happens if a terminating new-line character
>   isn't provided. Since the standard doesn't define the behavior, the
>   behavior is undefined.**